# UItableviewcell.contentview.height not returned as expected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 9) {
        height = 124.0f;
    }
    return height;
}
```

but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `44.0f` for indexPath.row == 9

Why is not returning 124?

Comment: The cell isn't sized in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It's sized later on. Don't rely on any cell dimensions in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Look into `willDisplayCellAtIndexPath`.

Comment: oh yeah...now I remember I did that before.

Comment: There are a couple of possible issues, where are you configuring the height var? Is it a class property? The value of 44 is the default value described in the design guide line from apple. Also, are you sure you don't set the tableView's rowHeight and estimatedHeight properties? Sorry about this another question, did you set the tableView's delegate properly? Could you include the tableView's instantiation related code, might be helpful for others to help you.